# numberSorter function only works with single digits

Tags: bootstrap-table

To show my problem, I adapted the "Custom sort with null/undefined" fiddle on the examples page at http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/

The issue is the numbers in the example sort fine because they are single digits but add a double digit eg 11, and it doesn't treat it as a number.. so you get for example 1, 11, 2 instead of 1, 2, 11

The new fiddle is
`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/ctn6424h/

Can anyone help improve the numberSorter javaScript so it actually can sort numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code for the `numberSorter()` function:

```
function numberSorter(a, b) {
    if (!parseInt(a)) return -1 * getOrder();
    if (!parseInt(b)) return 1 * getOrder();
    if (parseInt(a) < parseInt(b)) return -1;
    if (parseInt(a) > parseInt(b)) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that now works... really appreciate this solution - and it helps me see what the problem was coding-wise. Thanks!